# CS0592 Error - Compiler Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Good morning, 
I have a problem with the implementation of a readingfile class.

The error is

> Attribute "XmlElement" is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on property, indexer, field, parameter, return declaration

My code is here

```
  namespace obstacle_avoidance1
{
    //****************************************************Start definition of Simulation*********************************************
    [XmlRoot("Simulation")]
    public class Simulation
    {
         [XmlElement("Pedoni")]
         public Pedoni pedoni
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("Obstacles")]
        public Obstacles obstacles
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
    //****************************************************Implementation of Pedoni*********************************************
    //****************************************************Start implementation of Pedoni*********************************************

    [XmlElement("Pedoni")]   // ERROR
    public class Pedoni
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Number")]
        public int Number
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("Initial_Position")]
        public In_Pos initial_position
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("Final_Position")]
        public Fin_Pos final_position
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlAttribute("Velocity")]
        public double Velocity
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    //****************************************************End Pedoni********************************************************
    //****************************************************Implementation of Pedoni*********************************************
    [XmlElement("Initial_Position")]  // ERROR
    public class In_Pos
    {
        [XmlElement("X_In_Pos")]
        public double X_In_Pos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("Y_In_Pos")]
        public double Y_In_Pos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("Final_Position")]  // ERROR
    public class Fin_Pos
    {
        [XmlElement("X_Fin_Pos")]
        public double X_Fin_Pos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlElement("Y_Fin_Pos")]
        public double Y_Fin_Pos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to solve it? Maybe with a brief explanation in order to avoid in future the same error.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards

Comment: You have already specified `[XmlElement("Pedoni")]` at the property. You don't need to specify it again at the class.

Comment: @Wimmel 
Thanks for your reply. Now I don't receive any error message. 
Moreover I tried to do a Test but the result is always zero. 
Did I write any error in the reading implementation?

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Simulation));
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data.xml");
            Simulation simulation = (Simulation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
            MessageBox.Show("Simulation Information");
            MessageBox.Show("Number: " + simulation.pedoni.Number);
            MessageBox.Show("Velocity: " + simulation.pedoni.Velocity);

Comment: You need to show the input data (`data.xml`) before that can be answered. But please do so in a new question. Please check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).